# Is there a new incompatibility between ragged2e an scrlttr2?

Tags: line-breaking, koma-script, ragged2e

The following MWE used to work fine, but since I updated my TeX distribution yesterday (hadn’t done it in a while) it raises an error as soon as there appears more than on `\\` in the address. It works with `\newline` instead or when moving `\RaggedRight` inside `{letter}`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{ x \\ x \\ x }
\opening{Hi,}
Text
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{ x \\ x }
\opening{Hi,}
Text
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in `ragged2e` oder KOMA-Script? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Similar problems for me since I updated the koma-script bundle from version 3.26b to version 3.27. While not a proper solution, going back to the earlier version worked for me. However, I don't know where the actual problem lies...

Comment: It is imho a KOMA bug, it breaks also with a simple \raggedright. Basically the class does a `\protected@edef` on the second part of the address, and depending on the meaning of \\ it breaks.

Comment: Possible workarounds: `\AtBeginLetter{\RaggedRight}` in the preamble or `\begin{letter}{} \setkomavar{toname}{x} \setkomavar{toaddress}{x \\ x}` in the document.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback (and sorry for the delayed reply …).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KOMA-Script bug is fixed in the current [prerelease of the next KOMA-Script Version](https://komascript.de/node/1801) (will be 3.27a):

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}[2019/10/28]% needs at least version 3.27a.3319
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ x \\ x \\ x }
\opening{Hi,}
Recipient: \usekomavar{toname}, \usekomavar[\def\\{, }]{toaddress}

\lipsum[1]
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Possible workarounds for KOMA-Script Version 3.27:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\AtBeginLetter{\RaggedRight}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ x \\ x \\ x }
\opening{Hi,}
Recipient: \usekomavar{toname}, \usekomavar[\def\\{, }]{toaddress}

\lipsum[1]
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ x \\ x \protect\\ x }% <- changed
\opening{Hi,}
Recipient: \usekomavar{toname}, \usekomavar[\def\\{, }]{toaddress}

\lipsum[1]
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is to “robustify” `\@centercr` (which is the meaning `\\` is given under `\raggedright`).

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\makeatletter
\MakeRobust\@centercr
\makeatother

\raggedright

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{x\\ x \\ x}
\opening{Hi,}
Text
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

It's the same if you use `\RaggedRight`, because it uses `\@centercr` as well.